# Android - Show/Hide Toolbar in app on user touch with slide up and slide down animation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation, android-toolbar, android-fullscreen

I have implemented Show/Hide Toolbar when the user scrolls the list using `CoordinatorLayout`. And now I am working Show/Hide Toolbar in android app on user touch anywhere on the screen. I have tried this code and it is working fine:

```
        if (toolbar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

But the only problem is that toolbar does not animate while hiding or showing. I want that toolbar should slide up and slide down while hiding and showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (toolbar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    appbar.animate().translationY(-112).setDuration(600L)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }).start();
} else {
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    appbar.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(600L).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Motion Layout
Preview: https://giphy.com/gifs/jpn6QpmT3dBtf3XYIS

Depenedency `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6'`

On Design page of your layout find Component Tree and right click on your root layout, and then there you will see option saying 'Convert to MotionLayout'. It is recommended to do in that way. Because it automatically generates XMLfolder which holds MotionScene. If you don`t want to do in that way you can manually create a folder named `xml` and put activity_main_scene.xml inside it)

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
            android:id="@+id/motion_base"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main_scene.xml (Inside `xml` folder which is also inside res folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:duration="1000"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start">
        <OnClick
            motion:clickAction="transitionToEnd"
            motion:targetId="@+id/motion_base"/>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start" />

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code when doing click:

```
protected void toggleToolbarView() {
    isShown = !isShown;

    Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.TOP);
    transition.setDuration(200);
    transition.addTarget(toolbar);

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(toolbar, transition);

    toolbar.setVisibility(isShownHeaderFooter ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```